# Parsing values from CSV as strings into text file

Tags: python, xml, list, parsing, csv

I am attempting to create a txt file that includes XML files in a dir and the text within each XML files when a  tag is present.

I am having trouble reading a csv row in as a variable using the command below. I have attempted to pull the required values multiple ways but continue to run into a brick wall.

Here is the code:

```
container = raw_input("Choose a filename for your container:")
epub = zipfile.ZipFile( container + ".zip", 'w')
xmlinput = glob.glob('./*.xml')
def xmldrop(dir):
  for r,d,f in os.walk(dir):
     for files in f:
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            dom=parse(os.path.join(r, files))
            name = dom.getElementsByTagName('title')
            with open('catalog.csv', 'a') as f:
                f.write(files +  "," + name[0].firstChild.nodeValue  + "\n")
xmldrop("./")

line_number = 0
with open('catalog.csv', 'rb') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    text = mycsv[line_number+1][1]

list_tpl = '''
<Container>
<FileName>
%(FileName)s
</FileName>
</Container>'''
FileName = ""

for i, xml in enumerate(xmlinput):
    basename = os.path.basename(xml)
    FileName += ('<Fileid="%i" filename="%s"> <title>%s</title> </Fileid>' %
                 (i+1, basename, text))

epub.writestr('list.txt', list_tpl % {
  'FileName': FileName
})
```

I am able to successfully pull the information into a csv file as seen with this output:

> file_1.xml,Intro
>
> file_2.xml,Assessment
>
> file_3.xml,Review
>
> file_4.xml,Catalog

but the list.txt file that gets generated looks like:

```
<Container>
<FileName>
<Fileid="1" filename="file_1.xml"> <title>Assessment</title></p> </Fileid>
<Fileid="2" filename="file_2.xml"> <title>Assessment</title></p> </Fileid>
<Fileid="3" filename="file_3.xml"> <title>Assessment</title></p> </Fileid>
<Fileid="4" filename="file_4.xml"> <title>Assessment</title></p> </Fileid>
</FileName>
</Container>
```

Desired output would be:

```
<Container>
<FileName>
<Fileid="1" filename="file_1.xml"> <title>Intro</title> </Fileid>
<Fileid="2" filename="file_2.xml"> <title>Assessment</title> </Fileid>
<Fileid="3" filename="file_3.xml"> <title>Review</title> </Fileid>
<Fileid="4" filename="file_4.xml"> <title>Catalog</title> </Fileid>
</FileName>
</Container>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated. I have been trying to pair the two up for over a week now with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't updating the text variable when you are printing out your xml.
You set it once 
    text = mycsv[line_number+1][1]
but you never update it again, so it keeps outputting Assesment

Comment: How would you suggest updating the text variable if the number of files in the directory changes?

Comment: in your for loop just replace the text variable you are using in the string replacement with mycsv[i][1], which should work